# Регулярное выражение для удаления ссылок, в тексте которых встречается латиница

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно удалить все ссылки, где между тегами `a` встречаются латинские буквы.

Я попробовал сделать так:

```
preg_replace('#<a[^>]*>.*?</a>#is', '', $text);
```

Такое выражение удаляет вообще все ссылки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильное регулярное выражение выглядит так:

```
preg_replace('#<a[^>]*>.*?[a-z].*?</a>#is', '', $text);
```

Почему у вас ошибка:

В вашем случае, `.*?` захватывает максимально короткую последовательность из **любых** символов, стоящих до закрывающего тега `</a>`.

Вам же нужно выбрать только те ссылки, в которых встречаются латинские буквы.

Нужно заменить выражение `.*?` на `.*?[a-z].*?`, что означает буквально следующее: найти максимально короткую последовательность из **любых** символов, среди которых встретится **хотя бы одна латинская буква**.

Проверить работу можно на сервисе [**regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/vG1tP6/1).

---

#### Обновление

После замечания [`@Visman`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186083/visman) регулярное выражение стало таким:

```
preg_replace('#<a[^>]*>[^<]*?[a-z][^<]*?</a>#is', '', $text);
```

Отличие от предыдущей версии: мы ищем максимально короткую последовательность из **любых** символов, кроме `<`, среди которых встретится **хотя бы одна латинская буква**.

**Ограничения**

Регулярное выражение не захватит ссылку с таким текстом: `<a href="link"><latin></a>`, поскольку в тексте ссылки встречается символ `<`.

Проверить работу можно на сервисе [**regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/qS8bY7/3).

Comment: чтобы не тулить возле каждого символа * вопросительный знак, достоточно указать модификатор: "U - инвертирует жадность". Он уберет тем самым прожорливость.

Comment: @VladVlad, согласен, но обратите внимание, что в этой регулярке первая звездочка без вопросительного знака.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь!

Comment: @VenZell, прикол вашей регулярки в том, что она захватывает совсем не то, что ожидал вопрошающий https://regex101.com/r/qS8bY7/1

Comment: @Visman, я дополнил ответ. Спасибо за наблюдательность!

Comment: @Зоркий, обратите внимание на важное исправление.

Comment: @VenZell , и еще не все! `<a href="test" <!-- <<a href="test">xexe</a> -->>fake!</a>` нихт арбайтен)))

Comment: @Majestio, приведенный вами кусок html некорректен, да и сам пример далеко нетривиален. Если вы можете улучшить ответ, пожалуйста, оставьте ниже свой вариант, я за него проголосую. Полагаю, в этом случае, лучше использовать `DOMDocument`.